# Event Observer triggered in AppBundleA when service registered in AppBundleB

Tags: php, symfony, service, observers, event-listener

**SHORT**

I have an Event Observer that is triggered in AppBundleA. Even though I've registered the service in AppBundleB. Is this how services work? This is my first time using them.

**LONG**

I'm trying to implement the Before/After filters in my Symfony(v2.8) app using Event Subscribers:

- http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber

According to the example, I've registered the service globally in:

```
app/config/services.yml
```

The service worked and triggered correctly.

Next, I wanted to localize the service to a particular bundle so I moved the service registration to AppBundleB.

```
# AppBundleB\Resources\config\services.yml
services:
    app.tokens.action_subscriber:
        class: AppBundle\EventSubscriber\TokenSubscriber
        arguments: ['%tokens%']
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

However, when I ran a controller function in AppBundleA, it triggered the service above.

I don't believe this is supposed to happen. Does anyone have any ideas? Let me know if you need any other information.

**Symfony v2.8**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell services are triggered no matter where you place them.

This seems to be the way it was intended. Closing.